# Cronjob firing at wrong schedule.

Tags: cron, cron-task

i have two cronjobs, i want to run the two cronjobs at a small gap of ten minutes. once in two days, at 0100 hours and 0110 hours

this is what iam trying.

```
0 1 */2 * * job1.sh
10 1 */2 * * job2.sh
```

job1 is not working as expected. it runs twice everyday. 
job2 runs as expected (once in two days). 
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cronjob does not execute a script that works fine standalone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885909/cronjob-does-not-execute-a-script-that-works-fine-standalone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the binary executing the script, as well as the complete route to your file:

```
0 1 */2 * * /bin/sh /route/to/your/file/job1.sh
10 1 */2 * * /bin/sh /route/to/your/file/job2.sh
```

`/bin/sh` can be another thing, just get it from `which sh`.

Comment: my script has a #!/bin/sh in the start.

Comment: the scripts are running fine.. just that they are not firing at right time.. job1 is firing twice a day..

Comment: `0 1 */2 * *` is correct to schedule once every two days. It sound strange

Comment: By the way, although you have a `#!/bin/sh`, it is much recommendable to add `/bin/sh` to the cronjob line. Statistically, t is #1 solution for most problems.