# Cron shows me a script error

Tags: cron, centos

I have the next problem:
When I run my script from the unix shell (CentOS 6.7), my script runs without any error messages and works fine.

The problem appears when I try to execute it from a cron job at a specific time.

This is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

#Retrieve the status of the workstations into a file thanks to Nagios
echo -e "GET hosts\nColumns: address state\nFilter: address != 127.0.0.1" | unixcat /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/live > workstation_state.txt

#Read that file line by line
while read line
do
    IP=$(echo $line | cut -d ';' -f 1)
        STATE=$(echo $line | cut -d ';' -f 2)

        # Check the state of the workstation. If is 0, it means that is up, else is down
        # Only if the workstation is up we are going to connect through SSH and reload the device
        if [ $STATE -eq 0 ]
        then
                (echo "reload in 1"; echo "y"; echo "exit";) | sshpass -p 'K910p.,lo-16' ssh -A lab@$IP
        fi
done < workstation_state.txt
```

The Cron error says:

```
/root/reload-cisco.sh: line 4: unixcat: command not found
```

Why happens this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still get the same error when using `/full/path/to/unixcat`?

Comment: No, if I put the full path to unixcat the script works fine using a cron job.

Comment: so did that solve your problem?  I can post an answer so that this post can help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cronjob does not execute a script that works fine standalone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885909/cronjob-does-not-execute-a-script-that-works-fine-standalone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `which unixcat` to find the absolute path of the command, and use that in the script instead.  Use the full path for commands in crons because it might wipe your $PATH variable, which is presumably where all your binaries and executables are located --  so when the cron executes the script, it doesn't know where to look for the `unixcat` command.