# cron job not running in goDaddy shared host for laravel 5.2

Tags: cron, laravel-5

I am trying to run cron job in my laravel 5.2 application hosted in goDaddy shared host.

I have cPanel access and there I added a cron job, something like this:

```
* * * * * php /home/path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But the issue is that the server is not calling schedule action in Kernel.php. The same works fine in my local system.

Can anyone point out the mistake please or suggest some way to accomplish this so that server runs the cron job so as to execute defined commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cronjob does not execute a script that works fine standalone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885909/cronjob-does-not-execute-a-script-that-works-fine-standalone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add path of php binary to cron command.

```
* * * * * path/php /home/path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Example  : /usr/bin/php

Comment: this works fine, needed the php path like "/usr/local/bin/php" in my case

Answer (score 2):

#### Cpanel Cron job command in laravel godaddy and others are same

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/ivlssadmin/public_html/inventoryproject/artisan OpeningStocks:openingstocks >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here what you change follow bellow :

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/Your Host User Name /public_html/Sub Domain Name/artisan Command Name:Command Name >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

if you don't have sub domain you write only public html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you write the correct command in the schedule action. e.g. $schedule->command('**send:followup**')

Also check the timezone of the crontab if possible are you using utc timezone in your commands this is the default for most servers.

Comment: good point to mark on Theed but the issue has already been resolved. Thanks for the point BTW!